# Проблема с sftp на php

Tags: php, sftp

Имется следующий код:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($address ,$port);  
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass')){  
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);  
    $handle = scandir('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . '/home/user/');  
    echo $handle;  
    ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');  
    unset($connection);  
}
```

Проблема в том, что `echo $handle` ничего не выводит и нет никаких ошибок. Так же при попытках отправить файл через `ssh2_scp_send` - файл не отправляется и ошибок тоже нет.

Текст ошибки

> scandir(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #7/): failed to open dir: operation
>   failed in , scandir(): (errno 11): Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: А вы включили отображение ошибок?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, забыл включить. Теперь ошибки:scandir(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #7/): failed to open dir: operation failed in ,  scandir(): (errno 11): Resource temporarily unavailable in

Comment: А путь верный? Точно?

Comment: Да, путь верный. На передачу файлов всё так же не ругается и не передает.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить `echo getcwd()` перед `$handle = scandir('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . '/home/user/');` Это должно показать путь, где вы находитесь.

Comment: Ошибки могут возникать на стороне принимающего сервера и вы их не видите. Нужно их запросить. Например, я когда-то выполнял запросы на удалнном сервере с БД через тунель. `$result=ssh2_exec($ssh_connection, $ssh_query);
$error_result = ssh2_fetch_stream($result, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
stream_set_blocking($error_result, true);
print_r(stream_get_contents($result));
print_r(stream_get_contents($error_result));`

Comment: Показыает путь на на текущем сервере, т.е. с которого я запускаю скрипт

Comment: $result - это результат выполнения моего запроса. У вас другое что-то наверное. Попробуйте

Comment: А, тогда `exec('pwd',$return);print_r($return);`

Comment: exec('pwd',$return);print_r($return); тоже самое, директория текущего сервера

Comment: А, команды на удалённом сервере нужно выполнять с помощью `ssh2_exec()`

Comment: $stream= ssh2_exec($connection, 'pwd');
echo $stream; Получаю Resource id #8

Comment: Значит команда выполнилось. И нужно как-то вытянуть ответ. А как - это вопрос. Погуглите на гитхабе библотеки может какие для работы

Comment: stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
echo stream_get_contents($stream_out); вернуло то что надо

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос новыми фактами и т.п. Чтобы другие люди могли сразу в ситуацию вникнуть